# Access print connected to another switch

Tags: linux, ip, switch, printer

I have two servers (NethServer and Zend) "creating" two different IP pools. These two servers are connected to different switches, one of the switches has a printer connected. So, how do I make the computers on the other switch communicate with the printer?

I tried to create 3 Vlans(one for the computers of switch A, one for the computer of switch B and another for the printer connected in the switch B) and "trunk" the switches. But did not work.

[image: Image to Ilustrate]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need VLAN's at all. Just assign all of the devices with an ip address in the same network, such as 192.168.1.0/24.

Comment: So one of the servers need to generate IPs in the same as the other just with different "Start IP Adress"?

Comment: You only need one DHCP server in the network when all devices are on the same L2 broadcast domain.